# The meaning of "still-beating"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, adverbs, expressions

> I could hear a still-beating pulse of his heart.

Could it mean two things?

1. It is still beating. (still now)
2. It is beating quietly.

Comment: It is generally understood only as the first meaning: The heart continues to beat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this expression, *still* is the adverb with the temporal meaning: the heart has not stopped beating.

The position of *still* as a complement of a verb strongly pushes it to be interpreted as an adverb rather than an adjective. Although some informal dialects of English soften the boundary between adverbs and adjectives, the adjective *still*, meaning “not moving”, directly contradicts *beating*, so there is no risk of confusion.

There are other expressions about a heart where *still* can have the “not moving” meaning, for example “[be still, my heart](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_still_my_heart)”, which is a self-exhortation to be calm. In this expression, *still* is an adjective (like *quiet*), not an adverb (like *quietly*).