# to a still heady

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you help me understand what "to a still heady" means.  The text is:

> Boeing will “temporarily suspend production” of the 737 MAX in January as recertification issues drag on. Around 400 of the airliners have been built but not delivered since the grounding in March. The company trimmed production by 10 units a month (**to a still heady** 42) early in the crisis that has severely stressed Boeing’s reputation and impacted its market value.

I can understand "still" and "heady" sepearatly (maybe can understand). And I can understand this is of number of airplains.

Comment: Production was **52** units a month before they reduced it ***by** [some amount]* / ***to** [some amount]*. The amount they reduced it ***to*** was ***a** "still-heady" 42*. The actual amount (42) being adjectivally modified by ***heady = substantial***, which itself is adverbially modified by ***still = even now, after the reduction***. [Hyphenation optional.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+still-unsolved%2Ca+still+unsolved&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20still%20-%20unsolved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20still%20unsolved%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: From the answer to a related earlier question: [*The position of **still** as a complement of a verb strongly pushes it to be interpreted as an **adverb rather than an adjective**.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13251/126) Which I think *may* make this a duplicate.